# How to configure the .htaccess file for ErrorDocument working?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, errordocument

Good day! I'm doing the website on PHP. It will be a static site with limited count of pages. These pages have idential styles and scripts, so I wrote the **viewpage.php** script, which get the page name by URL and show it by PHP instruction **include** if such page is setted or put error 404 otherwise.
It is a structure of my website files:

```
admin/
     auth.php
     exit.php
     index.php
pages/
     index.php
     contacts.php
     ...
     err/
          err404.php
.htaccess
viewpage.php
```

and part of **viewpage.php**

```php
$pages = [
    "index/" => [
        "page"  => "index.php"
    ],
    "contacts/" => [
        "page" => "contacts.php"
    ],
];
...
$requestPage = $_GET[ "page" ] . "/";
if ( !array_key_exists( $requestPage, $pages ) ) {
    http_response_code( 404 );
    include "pages/err/err404.php";
    exit();
}
...
include "pages/$pageFile"; ?>
```

I want to allow the direct access to **site/admin/[index|auth|exit].php** and get such redirections:

```
site/admin/    => site/admin/index.php
site/          => site/viewpage.php?page=index
site/contacts  => site/viewpage.php?page=contacts
site/contacts/ => site/viewpage.php?page=contacts
otherwise      => site/pages/err/err404.php
```

I have tried this variant of .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/err/err404.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^admin$ admin/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)$ viewpage.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/$ viewpage.php?page=$1 [L]
```

but I have problems: I can't open main page by **site/**, only by **site/index/**
How me to configure the .htaccess file?

Comment: Re: "I can't open main page by **site/**, only by **site/index/**", what happens when you try to open it by **/site**?

Comment: @l'L'l, when I try to open **site/**, it's opens the list of files in root directory (I'm using the OpenServer and I did not write **Option -Indexes** to .htaccess)

Comment: Is there a reason you do not use **Option -Indexes**?

Comment: @l'L'l, no, there is not. I have tried just now, if I use this option, I get the 403 error when try to open **site/**

Comment: You get a `403` likely because you have no **index.html** or **index.php** in **/site**. So I think you'd want you rewrite to be like: 
`RewriteRule ^viewpage\.php\?page\=index\.php$ / [L]`

Comment: And the other one would be `RewriteRule ^viewpage\.php\?page\=(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L]
`

Comment: @l'L'l, I'm sorry, but may be you wanted write `RewriteRule ^/$ viewpage.php?page=index [L]` ? If it is, I tried this, but it was not worked, otherwise I do not understand the .htaccess file format

Comment: Yes, I was probably thinking backwards for whatever reason.

Comment: @l'L'l, it was not worked for me

Comment: I decided to simplify my task and renamed the file **viewpage.php** to **index.php**. Thank you!